# apt-get update failes to update

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apt

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 desktop edition mahcine. This machine is behind proxy server and content filter. I tried adding the following parameter in /etc/apt/apt.conf but it was not working after adding the ubuntu.com and the sites which are there in the sourcelist to content filter it started resolving the repo.

export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/

Now, the problem is the repo domains are resolving by doing apt-get update but not updating it.

Please help me.... Really this sucks.. I am finding this problem from last 2weeks... Please help....

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Is it that apt isn't using the proxy, or is it that the Packages files aren't downloading, or is it that you don't realise that `apt-get update` doesn't install packages?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line into /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@server:port/";
```

Or execute the command you wrote in the shell, from which you will launch apt-get. Note that exports are not persistent (you will have to add your exports to your profile or execute this command every shell launch manually).

Comment: I tried with what you have mentioned, Even its not working.

Comment: Did you try to download any package from the repository with "wget"? Don't forget to export http_proxy.     And one more. Are you shure, you use HTTP in apt, not FTP?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing wget. Even it said proxy authentication required after giving assigned.

Comment: Didn't understand you. :( Did download succeed? Or where did it stop? May be it is worth adding "-d" key to wget commandline?

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt-get update` only updates the Packages index (to give you info on what packages are newly available from the repostiory). To update the OS itself, run `apt-get upgrade`.